# Added incorrect rewrite rule now getting an error

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have made a mistake using add_rewrite_rule() function and now my site is throwing a 500 "internal server error" normally I would just edit/fix the issue in my .htaccess but since this is not how wordpress handles it i'm stuck!! I can't refresh permalink structure in wordpress because I can't load the site at all.

Any ideas?

[edit] I have cleared out the rewrite_rules entry in options in the database, still not working, error log shows:

RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` content.

Comment: Try to edit the site file by your FTP. Or run a backup.